# Quickest way to determine worst/best protocol, weakest/strongest cipher that a SSL server supported?

Tags: python, ssl, encryption, protocols

I'm writing a Nagios plugin that calculate that calculate SSL score based on Qualys Server Rating Guide: https://www.ssllabs.com/projects/rating-guide/

To do it, I need to find out which is the worst/best protocol and weakest/strongest cipher that a server supported.

Here're my code that use [sslyze](https://github.com/iSECPartners/sslyze):

```python
from plugins import PluginOpenSSLCipherSuites
from nassl import SSLV2, SSLV3, TLSV1, TLSV1_1, TLSV1_2


shared_settings = {'certinfo': 'basic', 'starttls': None, 'resum': True, 'resum_rate': None, 'http_get': True, 'xml_file': '/tmp/example.com_443.xml', 'compression': True, 'tlsv1': True, 'targets_in': None, 'keyform': 1, 'hsts': None, 'sslv3': True, 'sslv2': True, 'https_tunnel': None, 'nb_retries': 4, 'heartbleed': True, 'sni': None, 'https_tunnel_host': None, 'regular': False, 'key': None, 'reneg': True, 'tlsv1_2': True, 'tlsv1_1': True, 'hide_rejected_ciphers': True, 'keypass': '', 'cert': None, 'certform': 1, 'timeout': 5, 'xmpp_to': None}

target = ('example.com', '1.2.3.4', 443, TLSV1_2)

cipher_plugin = PluginOpenSSLCipherSuites.PluginOpenSSLCipherSuites()
cipher_plugin._shared_settings = shared_settings

protocols = ['sslv2', 'sslv3', 'tlsv1', 'tlsv1_1', 'tlsv1_2']
for p in protocols:
    cipher_result = cipher_plugin.process_task(target, p, None)
    cipher_result = cipher_plugin.process_task

    if any('Accepted' in c for c in cipher_result.get_txt_result()):
        worst_protocol = p
        break

for p in reversed(protocols):
    cipher_result = cipher_plugin.process_task(target, p, None)
    if any('Accepted' in c for c in cipher_result.get_txt_result()):
        best_protocol = p
        break

print(worst_protocol)
print(best_protocol)

ciphers = []
for protocol in ('sslv2', 'sslv3', 'tlsv1', 'tlsv1_1', 'tlsv1_2'):
    cipher_result = cipher_plugin.process_task(target, protocol, None)
    for e in cipher_result.get_txt_result():
        if 'bits' in e:
            ciphers.append(e.split()[1])

print(sorted(ciphers)[0])
print(sorted(ciphers)[-1])
```

but since there are a few loops, it took some time to complete.

With the following code, the execution time has been decreased from ~ 50s to ~ 40s. Is there anything else that I can turn to make it run faster?

```python
protocols = ['sslv2', 'sslv3', 'tlsv1', 'tlsv1_1', 'tlsv1_2']

ciphers = []

for p in protocols[:]:
    cipher_result = cipher_plugin.process_task(target, p, None)

    for c in cipher_result.get_txt_result():
        if 'rejected' in c:
            protocols.remove(p)
        if 'bits' in c:
            ciphers.append(c.split()[1])

worst_protocol = protocols[0]
best_protocol = protocols[-1]

weakest_cipher_strength = min(ciphers)
strongest_cipher_strength = max(ciphers)
```

Comment: Not even sure why you havn't just joined these three `for` loops into one single for loop, they use the same variables and call partially the same functions.. Just merge them..

Comment: @Torxed: Thanks, my question has been updated. Do you have any other idea?